# How to disable autologout for idle session in Ubuntu 20.04LTS server

Tags: 20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04LTS Server.iso on my laptops because I wanted a minimal XFCE4 which I succeed. But if I lock the screen of my user after a certain amount of time it automatically logout.

- I look for a TMOUT in profile. bashrc, /etc/bashrc,... without success
- I define TMOUT=0 without success too
- I thought it was `autolog` (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/autolog.8.html) but still, that program is not installed.
- I uninstall ubuntu-server but the autologout still remains.

So I come here because I'm out of a potential solution.

You did you experience something like this ? How did you fixed it ?

Answer (score 8):

You can modify it off on below item:

- Setting > Privacy > Screen Lock > Automatic Screen Lock (Off)

[image: .]
Then you should work fine with your wish.

Comment: from which X your screenshot is coming ? GNOMIUM ?